# Is it possible to get a data source URL of Google Spreadsheets for appengine datastore entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-visualization

Is it possible to get a data source URL of Google Spreadsheets for appengine datastore entities? I want to use the google visualization query objects to query my datastore. Or how I an expose my datastore with a datasource URL.

And for a Google visualization based project which one is better between Google Spreadsheet and GAE big table. Since Google Spreadsheet has very good query options and a nice harmonics with google visualization. One can get a direct DataTable from a data source URL. To do the same thing needs a good amount of task with GAE big table. Please share your experience in this area.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in to do this. You'll need to write your own code that returns your data in a format GViz supports.